# Batch file to process files in sub sub directory

Tags: batch-file

Given the folder structure

```
Folder0
    batfile.bat
    Folder1
        Folder1a
            file1a1
            file1a2
        Folder1b
            file1b
        Folder1c
            file1c1
            file1c2
```

How would I process the files file1a1, file1a2, etc.?

I'd like to try something like:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ('dir Folder0') do (for %%j in ('dir %%i') do <stuff to %%j>)
```

but A) it doesn't work and B) doesn't seem like the right approach anyway.

**Update:** 
I think I found something that *works*:

```
@echo off
cd %1
for /r %%i in (*.*) do echo %%i
```

where `echo` represents that thing I want to do to the file. However, I would like to be more explicitly traversing the directory structure so that I have a variable that represents the directory names. I ultimately want to put the processed files in a mirrored directory structure.

**Update 2:**
That doesn't quite work because once I cd into the lower directory, `batfile.bat` is one directory up, and I can't call it. I tried the equivalent of `"../batfile.bat"` and `../batfile.bat`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the folders with `for /d` command, combined with `pushd` and `popd` commands.

Read `help for` and `help pushd`, and try this code in a bat file

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
   echo %%a
   pushd %%a
   for /d %%b in (*) do (
     echo %%a/%%b
   )
   popd
)
```